# Transfer UK pension to AU super fund

Tags: united-kingdom, australia, pension, superannuation

Is it possible to transfer a UK pension fund over to an Australian Super fund?

I am a NZ citizen currently working in the UK. I will most likely move back to Australia in a year or two, where I spent most of my working life prior to moving to the UK.

Comment: Of interest, from a google search (article dated December 3, 2018) - [How do I transfer a UK pension to an Australian super fund?](https://www.superguide.com.au/boost-your-superannuation/how-do-i-transfer-a-uk-pension-to-an-australia-super-fund)